# Wordpress main path loads slow

Tags: wordpress, performance

I'm facing problem with loading my site.
After accesing site, it takes from 400ms to 4000ms before receiving the first byte (TTFB).

Rest of the site is loaded rapidly : ~1.2s with 1.7MB of files and ~73 requests, with access time that differs from 16ms to 70ms.

My biggest concern here is why my main path of the site is sometimes loaded quickly in 400ms and then it can lag to the whole 4s with just press of 'refresh' button.

My site : 
https://mm.bartoszwas.pl

GTMetrix Performance report from today : 
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/mm.bartoszwas.pl/mKOrtfWm

**What i already did:**

1. Hosting response test - `ping www.mm.bartoszwas.pl` gave me result of 15ms
2. Putting small php file into my child-theme to check access time (15ms)
   https://mm.bartoszwas.pl/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/test.php
3. Links changed to **HTTPS** from normal **HTTP** - to avoid redirects.
4. Links in **wp-config** and **database** updated to *HTTPS*
5. Disabled plugins
6. Installed **WP Total Cache** plugin - but sometime it work, sometime it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding an issue without caching plugin in place, because when you have caching enabled it is just serving cached version which will be quick. It can be slow when cache is flushed and your server is re-generating all the content in order to cache it again. 
So I would suggest you to disable total cache plugin and then try running pingdom or gtmetrix.

Try wordfense. Maybe you have downloaded some nulled plugin that has malicious code and it makes some external calls before your page is being loaded.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. Seems like caching plugin even worsen the performance, and it wasn't even caching. But problem still appears.

Comment: Site is loading quickly on my side. Try using chrome's incognito mode or other browser. Maybe you have some chrome extensions that are injecting js code into your site that might be affecting perfermance.